# Can I chant mantras without initiation?

Tags: mantras, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, shaivism

I want to meditate on Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva. But I have read at many places on the internet that before chanting a mantra one must receive it from a guru. What another option do I have? I currently chant vishnu sahasranamam daily.

Comment: It is not necessary for you to receive a mantra from guru, however guru can help you with the correct pronunciation/procedure. Also if you receive it from a guru, you can progress quicker.

Comment: @cartman Are you sure? I have read that if chanted without a guru it has disastrous effects.

Comment: It is what you believe in. For Soumya devatas as long as you have the pronunciation right, it shouldn't matter. If you're praying ugra devatas like Kali make sure you have guru.

Comment: @cartman Okay, thank you.

Comment: @hichika, would you directly try long jump before you can walk ? if you are just a beginner, you start with chanting names of Bhagavan. Once you gain spiritual samskara, then automatically, you'll approach a guru for mantra.

Comment: This sounds like a personal advice question which are not allowed. See this note on the side panel: "Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor."

Comment: @ram Thank u for your advice

Comment: @sv. Sorry... Actually I am new here.

Comment: No issues. You can edit and make it generic (remove any personal information and all the I's), so it applies to others as well. But there are other questions of the same nature, so your question maybe closed as dup. of these. E.g., see [Chanting hymns require guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3352) and [Can I chant these stotras without initiation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29277)

Comment: @sv. Done so...

Comment: I do not think Vishnu Sahasranamam needs initiation. In general, a *mantram* will need initiation, a *stotram* does not need initiation. *Mantram* have more restrictions than *stotrams*

Comment: Yes you can chant without a guru. It is optional. A guru is handy because he can give you guidance but it is not required. You can ask the trimurti to guide you.

Comment: Still looks like a personal advice question. Also, seems like duplicate of the two questions  linked above.

Answer (score 2):

You NEVER needed a Guru for obtaining any knowledge. Who was Valmiki's Guru??? Who explained him the biography of Rama? NONE.

Who was Eklavya's Guru??? You may say Dronacharya, but no he was not. Eklavya considered him as a Guru when he watched him teach the pandavas and kauravas.

When you meditate and you are lost from materialistic world, you gain knowledge without you realizing it.

Recite - OM NAMA SHIVAY to make Shiva come to you and 
recite Acyutananda Govinda to bring Vishnu to you.
And remember both are one and same.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! You should cite some sources while answering questions. Opinions only is not endorsed here